# Template "inheritance"

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, inheritance, xslt-1.0

I have 2 templates in my XSL which should both apply to the same node, but one is more specific than the other

e.g. for this xml

```
<root>
  <a/>
  <a attr="1" attr2="2"/>
</root>
```

and this xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  base template
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="a[@attr]">
  specific
</xsl:template>
```

Normally XSL will apply only one of these templates.
However in my more specific template I also want to apply everything that is in the less specific template.

Answer (score 4):

XSLT 2.0 has the [`<xsl:next-match/>` instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-next-match) for this purpose, but in 1.0 the only generic option is to put the less-specific template in a separate XSLT file, `<xsl:import>` it and then use `<xsl:apply-imports/>`.  If you know precisely *which* "less specific template" you want to use then the alternative is to give that template a `name` as well as a `match` and then call it using `<xsl:call-template name="overridden"/>` but that bypasses the matching mechanism - you have to decide which template you are overriding rather than letting the engine find the "next best".

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with 1.0.

I'd prefer not to have multiple XSLs if possible (this is only a small thing)

Answer (score 0):

"Inheritance" does not have a clear-cut meaning in XSLT. Inheritance is an object-oriented concept that applies to classes and objects - which do not exists in a functional paradigm.

An `xsl:apply-templates` without a `select` attributes does *not* apply other templates that match the same, current node.

Instead, it instructs the XSLT processor to process the remaining input nodes and leaves the choice of the appropriate templates to do so to the processor. In other words, this does not lead to the same node being processed twice.

Now, consider the following stylesheet (which is essentially your solution):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        base template
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[@attr]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        specific
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the context of the template match `a[@attr]`, `<xsl:apply-templates/>` means:

> process all available child nodes (all elements `*`, processing-instruction(), comment(), all attributes @*, text()) of the current node.

In your input XML, there is only one `a` node that is matched by this template. It only has attribute nodes, which are not output by default.

---

> Normally XSL will apply only one of these templates. However in my more specific template I also want to apply everything that is in the less specific template.

There are several solutions to this (e.g. store reusable content in a named template and call it, import external stylesheets, use variables, use template priorities, use `xsl:choose`). But first you'd have to reveal [what exactly you'd like to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Could you explain more about how to use template priorities in this instance?

Comment: What I'd like to achieve is exactly what I stated - the more specific template should also apply less specific ones. Ideally at a specific point though in this situation that's not a requirement, in fact the order is not even relevant.

Comment: @DJL It is impossible to say whether template priorities solve your problem. You have not given enough information to give a sound, specific answer. To make it crystal-clear you could: show an actual input and output XMl file (that is, the output you expect vs. the one you get) and your _entire_ attempted XSLT stylesheet. This would enable people to help you.

Comment: @DJL To make this even clearer: You have to consider the possibility that you do not really need to have two templates match the same node, in order to achieve your goal. Perhaps you are on the wrong track and the solution is actually something else.

Answer (score -3):

This answer is incorrect

Using

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

with no `select` attribute applies other templates that also match the current node

This XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  base template
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="a[@attr]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  specific
</xsl:template>
```

results in the following output:

```
base template
specific
```

I haven't investigated what might happen if there is more than 1 more specific template which chains as above.

Comment: No, `<xsl:apply-templates/>` with no `select` is the same as `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` and applies templates to all the child nodes (elements, text nodes, PIs and comments) of the current node.

Comment: In this case it's selecting nothing - the `base template` is the result of the template that matched the _first_ `<a/>` and the `specific` comes from the one matching the `<a attr="1" attr2="2"/>`

Comment: What @IanRoberts said.  Moreover, if you try to work around this by issuing `<xsl:apply-templates select="." />` then get ready to kill your process because you will end up in an infinite recursion.

Comment: @harpo In principle, that is true, but most XSLT processor will catch this and issue a warning along the lines of: "Too many nested apply-templates calls"

Comment: @MathiasMüller, heh, I guess .NET's processor is more principled than most — specifically regarding the right to shoot yourself in the foot.  (Actually it's a very good implementation.)

Comment: @harpo - yes this stung me!